# How can I convert a bitmask value to an array using Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, bitmask

I would like to convert an integer value, representing a bitmask, to an array holding corresponding values. For example, the value `3` should be converted to `[1, 2]` (I am happy with any conversion, as long as it's an array and it's unique and easy to query). As much as possible I'd like to avoid using a custom UDF.

I am able to use the following (example is for the constant input of 7):

```sql
select filter(array(1 * bit_get(7, 0), 2 * bit_get(7, 1), 3 * bit_get(7, 2)), x -> x > 0);
```

However, this is rather cumbersome and hard to maintain when the number of bits grow.

Is there a better way to achieve this goal, without use of UDFs?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula no - vanilla Spark

Comment: can you please add your input & expected output ?

Comment: An example input would be 7, and the output [1, 2, 3] (because 7 is 111); another example input is 6, for which I'd expect [2, 3] (because 6 is 110).